# How to simulate end of file

Tags: c++, windows

I was typing input from the command terminal into my C++ program (compiled under MinGW).

Now I want to simulate an end-of-file. Is there a shortcut for that? I know normally it is CTRL+C, but that does not work here.

Comment: Not CTRL + C, CTRL + Z. Try this one instead. CTRL + C is SIGINT.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you normally use F6. On Linux, Ctrl-D. Pressing that immediately after pressing Enter tends to work best.

Answer (score 2):

Try CTRL + Z instead of CRTL + C.

Answer (score 0):

I know Control-Z works in copy con (in batch files). But if you are on windows machine, the end of line charater is '\r\n'. That is equivalent to ASCII (13)(10). To simulate them, you can use CTRL+key combination to enter the ascii code. [Here is the reference](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html)

According to this you would need

```
Ctrl + M   //  (CR)
Ctrl + J   //  (LF)
```

You will need both of these one after the other (in the same order).